# Использование символа '<' в значении атрибута

Tags: android, xslt

Есть xsl файл, но Eclipse ругается на следующую строчку:

```
<xsl:when test="count(ancestor::node()) < 9">
```

Вот ошибка:

> The value of attribute "test"
> associated with an element type
> "xsl:when" must not contain the '<'
> character.

Как можно исправить?

Comment: Может, эту проверку `count(ancestor::node()) < 9`, можно сделать перед формированием файла?

Comment: Если честно, я не знаю xsl. Парсю книжку, все нормально, но вот 1 косяк...

Comment: Угу исправил, спс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрещенный символ, гугли (как &, >, <), заменяются так же, как и в xml.